# Google Sheets Formula assistance

Tags: filter, google-sheets, formula, lookup

first time poster here.

I think this is the first time I've not managed to find what I'm looking for via the search.

I have recently started a project to increase my understanding of Excel/Google Sheets. This project is something I will be doing in my own time with no financial gain.

I am however having some difficulty with my formulas. What I'm looking for is a nudge in the right direction or maybe an example from someone more experienced than me. I have linked a Google Sheets document below for anyone interested in helping me with my formulas.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mY13e-75dBYfKgkjV8dFFFEvxC838nGNxPrUdusc0PA/edit?usp=sharing

Anyone using the above link has comment capability.

As you can see my formula in the "results" cells will search my "Dishwasher data" sheet and pull all the relevant data through to the correct cell. While this was completely intended (took me ages), I would like to add a second alternative criteria to my search.

While I want to be able to search by "product code" I also want the ability to search by "Model number", as an alternative means of searching and pulling the data through. I have tried a few different things like using IFERROR instead of ISERROR etc. I just cant seem to figure it out.

Part 2:

The second stage of my project was to have a more advanced search tool. You will see the "tools" under "list searches". 
Example 1, I want to be able to search and display a list of all models under or equal to "X dB", the list should be displayed under D13,J13 and below.

The more complex of the two "advanced" searches would be the decor panel height. Displaying all models where the "customer decor panel height" is between the max and min the appliance can support. So a <=Max >=Min formula, but I still have no idea how to form a list with all "viable" options.

I'm assuming some sort of FILTER can be used possibly?

Again this ties in with my first formulaic issue, I do not understand how to have optional or alternative criteria in a formula that can both be displayed in the same cell range.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left some comments on your sheet regarding using list of items rather than typing in values.

I've made a copy of your sheet and can lookup things via model number or product code.

I used this in the product code lookup

```
=If(A4>0,vlookup(A4,'Dishwasher Data'!B:I,1,False),vlookup(A7,'Dishwasher Data'!A:I,2,FALSE))
```

This looks at cell A4, if it has data, it looks it up, if there is no data in A4, it will lookup A7 instead (Model number)

This formula can be repeated in the sheet and adjusted.

For the filter on the noise level.

Put this somewhere and enter a noise level.

```
=FILTER('Dishwasher Data'!A:A,'Dishwasher Data'!H:H <=A11)
```

At the moment it's only returning the Model number. 
If you wanted the whole table, change `'Dishwasher Data'!A:A` to `'Dishwasher Data'!A:I`

Here is my demo sheet.
[My demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18YwEzJpvz8GNuPP83M7jhAkYvHGOe57EHnX3KUwyOSE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think I love you. So all that was actually needed was an argument if there was no value in A4... So simple >.> Thank you.

Comment: @McSheehy lol no worries, if it answers your question, please mark it as answered. Let me know if you need any other help

Comment: Using an IF statement to see if A4 is zero or greater (I.E it has something in it) seems the easiest way to me to choose a lookup on model or product code. But do bear in mind, if you want to search by model code. Product code must be BLANK

Comment: Much appreciated! I think I can reverse engineer the rest of the formulas I need!

Comment: I've ran into an issue with Vlookup, When I search by Model number the Product code and model number switch columns. As you said Vlookup take info to the right of the search criteria. Is there anyway for their formula to dynamically adjust to this?